# Add multithreading layer to Asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I currently have this piece of code running just fine using AsyncIO.

```
async def main():

    while(1):
        loop.create_task(startAsyncJob())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def startAsyncJob():
    #myCodeHere


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I tried to add a multithreading layer so I can run concurrently multiple pieces of what inside my "main". So I extracted its code, put it in its own function `AsyncJobThread` that I launch through my new main function using threads:

```
def main():

    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread( AsyncJobThread, (1))
        _thread.start_new_thread( AsyncJobThread, (15))
    except:
        print ("Error: unable to start thread")

async def AsyncJobThread(frequence):
    while(1):
        loop.create_task(startAsyncJob())
        await asyncio.sleep(frequence)


async def startAsyncJob():
    #myCodeHere

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

However the current implementation gives me the following error:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncJobThread' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: You can’t mix threads and asyncio like that. You’d need to run a new event loop inside each thread. Why not use something like `asyncio.gather` to run multiple things at once instead?

Comment: Never used anything like this, I actually just started using asyncio yesterday. Could you detail how you would do this with `asyncio.gather` in an answer please?

Comment: @dirn Thanks I just tried using a new event loop for each thread and it worked.

Comment: On a side note, there is no reason to use `_thread` instead of `threading.Thread`. (or, there might be, but you'd really need to know what you are doing). Asa reule of thumb, if something starts with `_` in Python you should not use it directly (it is the equivalent of "private" variables in other languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's your code modified to use `asyncio.gather`.

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        AsyncJobThread(1),
        AsyncJobThread(15),
    )

async def AsyncJobThread(frequence):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.create_task(startAsyncJob())
        await asyncio.sleep(frequence)


async def startAsyncJob():
    #myCodeHere

asyncio.run(main())
```

You could also get a reference to the loop and pass it into `AsyncJobThread` if you prefer.